# xfce4-screenshooter creates something invalid in clipboard when taking screenshot

Tags: virtualbox, xfce, clipboard

I installed `xfce4-screenshooter-plugin` on my xfce VirtualBox Debian 8 and. with use of `xfce4-screenshooter --help` I bound <kbd>PrScr</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PrScr</kbd> to capture full screen and active window screenshots respectively:

[image: image description]

This can be done in Settings`->`Keyboard`->`Application Shortcuts. However when I use this, as well as when I just run the command, clipboard contains data that neither MSPaint on real machine (I'm using VirtualBox), nor GIMP (running in the VirtualBox) can process. When I paste, I get loading cursor animation. MSPaint eventually shows this dialog:

[image: image description]

GIMP just silently fails and pastes nothing. ClipMan, however, has no problem reading the image and showing it in history:

[image: image description]

If I click that history item, the image is no longer corrupted and can be pasted in both image editors.

I just wonder: what's wrong? Is there something I need to configure or is just the plugin broken?

**Edit:**

Based on comments I tried another plugin, this is output of Gnome screenshot utility:

```
XXXXX@debianvirtualbox:~/$ gnome-screenshot -w -c
** Message: Unable to use GNOME Shell's builtin screenshot interface, resorting to fallback X11.
```

Again, nothing appeared in clipboard. However if I copy something before triggering the command it's gone when it terminates.

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl+Shift+V to paste as a new image in gimp? I doubt it will make a difference but you may as well try. Could it be that ClipMan is the problem? Have you tried pasting when ClipMan is not running?

Comment: ClipMan is not causing the issue and is only workaround so far (just tested). But now, after restarting clipman, I can't get any screenshots in clipboard at all. Neither after shuting it down again.

Comment: Strange. Perhaps Xfce is using the wrong clipboard and can't deal with complex data. Do you have the same issue with another screenshot program, `gnome-screenshot` for example?

Comment: @terdon gnome doesn't work either.  I noticed that although it doesn't put image in clipboard it manages to clean it.

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it more ovvious what is runningwhere? (Paint, GIMP, ClipMan, xfce-screenshooter, ...)

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher Better?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a temporary file and then feed that to a new Gimp process, like this:

```
xfce4-screenshooter -w --open /usr/bin/gimp
```

(screenshooter will create a file in /tmp and pass the filename as argument to gimp)