# xfce4-screenshooter cannot use clipboard

Tags: xfce, screenshot

I am currently experiencing the problem described in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233257/xfce4-screenshooter-creates-something-invalid-in-clipboard-when-taking-screensho) question on an up-to-date, non-VM Arch Linux installation: `xfce4-screenshooter` creates invalid data in the clipboard.  Any application into which I attempt to paste the screenshot will hang for about half a minute, then either complain about invalid data or fail silently.

I have tried all of the suggestions found in the linked question.  No combination of `xfce4-screenshooter` or `gnome-screenshot` with or without `xfce4-clipman` creates a pasteable image.  This is the case for both the GUI and CLI tools.

Choosing to open the screenshot with an application using the XFCE tool's GUI works, but not via CLI; this is unacceptable for me as my goal is to bind a key to run the screenshot command.  I have also noticed that selecting the image in the Clipman plugin's history menu renders it usable, though I find this to be inelegant as well.

One year and nine months after that question was asked, has anybody found a workaround/solution, or at least an explanation as to why this feature which every other desktop seems to have does not work in XFCE?

I'd appreciate any answers to this, of course, but ideally I'd like to be able to bind

```
xfce4-screenshooter --fullscreen --clipboard
```

to the PrintScreen key, enabling me to take and paste a screenshot by doing nothing more than a couple quick keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: In view of the apparent presence of a bug in `xfce4-screenshooter` that's causing the problem (see my answer below), the quickest workaround is to use a different screenshot program. For example, Flameshot (https://flameshot.js.org) works where `xfce4-screenshooter` fails by using the command `flameshot full -c`.

Comment: Have this issue too : segfault when using to clipboard mode. Similar issue with gnome-screenshot. The segfault does not occurs every time. Except for gnome-screenshot if started on GUI mode it works every time but it segfault in selection mode directly. As suggested, I've changed for flameshot and replaced the shortcut

Answer (score 1):

From several tests of `xfce4-screenshooter` using its GUI, I've concluded that there's a bug in `xfce4-screenshooter` pertaining to allocation of space for the screenshot.

My display is 1920x1080. If taking either a fullscreen screenshot or a screenshot of maximized window (which excludes areas with desktop panels), then copying to the clipboard, and pasting fails. However, if the maximized window is reduced in size a small but not insignificant amount, then a screenshot of the window, copy to clipboard, and paste works.

Guess the next step is to submit a bug report if one hasn't been submitted already.